# Swift button not showing on tableviewcell when app is run

Tags: swift, uitableview, button, cell

I have a quick simple question for you. I have a tableview and want to add a button(which is a star image) to every cell. Thus in the storyboard I drag a button into my tableview prototype cell. I can see perfectly that there is a button in the main.storyboard in my cell but, when I run the app no button is appearing in any tableview cell. How can I fix this issue? I'd appreciate any help!!

Comment: If you are using a **custom** cell you have to use also a **custom** class otherwise a standard `UITableViewCell` is dequeued.

Comment: @vadian just like a normal tableview there are texts in every cell but now I also want to add a star icon(button) next to each text. Is custom class the only way to manage this issue? If yes, how can I create one?? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: To have access to the button you must create a custom class. Create (⌘N) a new Cocoa Touch subclass of `UITableViewCell` with a meaningful name, in Interface Builder set the class of the custom cell to that class and force downcast the dequeued table view cell to that subclass in `cellForRow`.

Comment: @vadian can you explain more clearly what you mean by "force downcast the dequeued table view cell to that subclass in cellForRow". I'm sorry for asking so many questions, I'm a bit new to Swift :-(

Comment: Please search google for *uitableview custom cell swift*. There are a lot of good tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create custom class for tableViewCell, and with this class, you can add your button. [It's similar like in this tutorial](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/), just instead of images, you can add buttons. On youtube you can find some good tutorial as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help!